# C# HttpWebRequest enviar multipart/form-data em POST

Tags: c#, .net

Estou precisando enviar um `POST` usando `HttpWebRequest`, com o header `Content-Type=multipart/form-data` e `Accept=multipart/form-data`, e o dados no `Body`.

A minha rotina abaixo, eu utilizo ela sem problemas fazendo `POST`, enviando dados no formato `Json`.

#### Problema

Preciso colocar na rotina atual, parâmetros para o `multipart/form-data`, e já tentei de vários jeitos, mas nenhum funcionou.

Os dados que tenho que enviar são, 3 campos de texto.

#### Rotina Atual

```
protected virtual RetornoSolicitacao Executa(Operacao operacao, string urlBase, string urlServico, string dados)
{
    HttpWebRequest requisicao = MontaRequisicao(urlBase, urlServico);           

    byte[] dadosFormatados = Encoda(dados);
    requisicao.ContentLength = dadosFormatados.Length;

    Stream requisicaoDados = requisicao.GetRequestStream();
    requisicaoDados.Write(dadosFormatados, 0, dadosFormatados.Length);
    requisicaoDados.Close();

    HttpWebResponse resposta;

    resposta = (HttpWebResponse)requisicao.GetResponse();

    resultado.HttpCodigoRetorno = (int)resposta.StatusCode;
    var respostaTexto = new StreamReader(resposta.GetResponseStream());
    resultado.Retorno = respostaTexto.ReadToEnd();
}
```

#### Requisição

```
protected virtual HttpWebRequest MontaRequisicao(string urlBase, string urlServico)
{
    HttpWebRequest requisicao = default(HttpWebRequest);

    Uri url = new Uri(new Uri(urlBase), urlServico);
    requisicao = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    
    requisicao.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
    requisicao.Accept = "multipart/form-data";                                    
    requisicao.Method = "POST";
    requisicao.Timeout = ConfiguarTimeOut(_configuracao.Configuracao) * 1000;               
    requisicao.Headers.Add("Authorization", chaveAutorizacao);               

    return requisicao;          
}
```

Comment: Que q ta rolando? ta dando erro? Ele simplesmente não envia?

Comment: @Francisco dá erro 500 e 415. No PostMan consigo enviar, mas não consegui entender para colocar no C#

Comment: Quando é assim eu uso o Fiddler para capturar a requisição dos 2. Assim eu posso fazer a comparação

Comment: Este site https://www.telerik.com/fiddler @Francisco

Comment: No Postman do lado direito da requisição que esta aceitando tem um botão chamado "Code", verifica se todos os items do cabeçalho que o Postman gera esta igual a sua requisição do C#.

Comment: @GabrielColetta o pior que já verifiquei ele e não estou achando o problema. De forma aparente é tudo igual. Agora estou testando `ContentType` e `Accept` com outros tipos. Conforme esta resposta do SO está correto a forma de colocar os dados https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256136/setting-a-webrequests-body-data. Vou testar e já respondo.

Comment: Qual foi o resultado que obteve?